# Rails Mechanize Loop within loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mechanize

Hi I have a mechanize task set up to loop through some listings and get basic info and save to csv

```
task :melrooftop => :environment do
  require 'mechanize'
  require 'csv'

  mechanize = Mechanize.new
  mechanize.history_added = Proc.new { sleep 10.0 }
  mechanize.ignore_bad_chunking = true
  mechanize.follow_meta_refresh = true
  page = mechanize.get('https://www.theurbanlist.com/melbourne/directory/search/eyJyZXN1bHRfcGFnZSI6Im1lbGJvdXJuZVwvZGlyZWN0b3J5XC9zZWFyY2giLCJrZXl3b3JkcyI6IlJvb2Z0b3AiLCJjYXRlZ29yeTpidXNpbmVzc190eXBlIjoiMiJ9')
  results = []
  results << ['name', 'streetAddress', 'addressLocality', 'postalCode', 'addressRegion', 'addressCountry', 'telephone', 'url', 'tags']

page.search('a[title="view business"]').each do |link|
    mechanize.click(link)

    name = mechanize.page.css('article h1[itemprop="name"]').text.strip
    streetAddress = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="streetAddress"]').text.strip
    addressLocality = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="addressLocality"]').text.strip
    postalCode = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="postalCode"]').text.strip
    addressRegion = mechanize.page.css('address span span[itemprop="addressRegion"]').text.strip
    addressCountry = mechanize.page.css('address span meta[itemprop="addressCountry"]').text.strip
    telephone = mechanize.page.css('address span[itemprop="telephone"]').text.strip
    url = mechanize.page.css('article p a[itemprop="url"]').text.strip
    results << [name, streetAddress, addressLocality, postalCode, addressRegion, addressCountry, telephone, url, tags]
  end

  CSV.open("melrooftop.csv", "w+") do |csv_file|
    results.each do |row|
      csv_file << row
    end
  end
```

Inside this loop I would like to collect a list of tags and add them to my results.

Can I just add a loop within my loop with the below?

```
  tags = []
    tags = mechanize.page.css('div[class="column medium-3 __left-col-small"] article ul li').each do |tag|
      tag.text.strip
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes or you can do it on one line:

```
tags = page.search(css).map{|el| el.text}
```

Comment: what does the el mean? or is it something you created as a placeholder? when you say css, you mean add my css there?

Comment: Yes, those are variables. el is the html element.

Comment: So that should have been li? If we are using my example?

Comment: This is just a general case suggestion. You should be able to adapt it to your issue. If you can't, you should consider hiring a freelancer.

Comment: If you could edit your answer so that it directly references the question, I can market it right and give you the kudos for the whelp you gave :)

Comment: I'm going to leave a little bit as an exercise for you. Wax on, wax off.

Comment: appreciate that mate, waxed on, waxed off :)